# jScrollPane - MouseWheel not working

Tags: scrollbar, jscrollpane, mousewheel, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane, simply because it was the first thing on Google and I'm very tired. So, I'll start by saying that I'm not opposed to using something different.

I've got a 2-column section. The right column uses the jScrollPane plugin and has a fixed width. It works when you drag the scrollbar, but the mouse wheel plugin doesn't seem to work. I'm calling everything in this order:

```
jquery.jscrollpane.css  
jquery.jscrollpane.lozenge.css  
jquery.min.js  
jquery.mousewheel.js  
mwheelIntent.js  
jquery.jscrollpane.min.js
```

The markup:

```
<div class="twocolumn">
  <div class="img-lt"></div>
  <div class="txt-rt scroll-pane">...</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#content .twocolumn { overflow:hidden; }
#content .twocolumn .img-lt {
  padding-right:22px;
  border-right:1px solid #818283;
  float:left;
}
#content .twocolumn .txt-rt {
  padding-left:22px;
  float:left;
  width:556px;
  height:409px;
}
```

And is targeted on page ready via
`$(function(){ $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(); });`

Console reports no errors. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I Am guessing you are using jQuery 1.7. If so, the plugin that control the scrollwheel needs to be update. (one of the dependencies in the jScrollPane plugin).

Here is the link:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/

Comment: Great catch! I downgraded to 1.6.4, and everything works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't have to downgrade jQuery I think. Just upgrade the scrollwheel plugin I linked to. It is one of the dependencies for jScrollPane. Good luck! :)